Как лучше разделить предложение на абзацы?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше расставить знаки препинания и абзацы?
— Это интересно. — Он медленно обдумывал сказанные ею слова. Наблюдая за его напряжённым лицом, она внезапно выпалила(?)
— Я всё для себя решила. И это решение не обсуждается.
Как вообще правильнее поступить в таких ситуациях, когда слова автора, после которых должна идти прямая речь, а следовательно ставиться двоеточие, присоединены к предыдущим словам автора? Всегда ли нужно разделять их в разные абзацы?

Я бы записала так:
— Это интересно.
Он медленно обдумывал сказанные ею слова. Наблюдая за его напряжённым лицом, она внезапно выпалила:
— Я всё для себя решила. И это решение не обсуждается.
Пояснение
Розенталь § 53. Абзацы при прямой речи
 4. Если между двумя репликами одного и того же говорящего 
 лица находится текст от автора, то ни этот текст, ни 
 последующая прямая речь в отдельные абзацы обычно не 
 выделяются:
 — Не получается что-то у меня с проводом, — ответил мастер. 
 Он немного подумал и добавил: — Придётся всё делать заново.

 Но если в тексте от автора описывается действие говорящего 
 лица, то и авторский текст, и последующая прямая речь 
 выделяются в абзацы:
 — Формула эта может иметь и другой вид, — пояснил 
 профессор.
 Он неторопливо подошёл к доске, взял мел и написал что-то 
 новое для нас.
 — Вот это и есть другой вариант, — сказал он.

В приведенном примере после первой реплики идет авторский текст (описание действий персонажей), и лучше его весь выделить в отдельный абзац.

Благодарю за ответ! А как поступить в таком случае: "— Это интересно, — протянул он, а она следом вскочила с места и внезапно выпалила (?) — Я всё для себя решила. И это решение не обсуждается."?

— Это интересно, — протянул он, а она следом вскочила с места и внезапно выпалила: — Я всё для себя решила. И это решение не обсуждается." Ее  реплику нужно перенести в отдельный абзац, так как это реплика другого лица (не его).
